# Calculating the total loss in the longest losing streak

Tags: java

A sequence of consecutive numbers in which each number is less than equal to the previous number is called a losing streak. The difference in value between the last number and the first number of the streak is known as the loss.

For example if these numbers are provided on standard output:

```
3, 6, 36, 32, 32, 121, 66, 24, 22, 371, 661, 6, 4, 8.
```

The longest streak in the sequences are `36,32,32` and `121,66,24,22` and `661,6,4` and the corresponding losses are 4 and 99 and 657. In this case the 2nd Streak with 4 numbers is the longest. So the program should print the output as 99.

I tried with below program but could not get it right:

```
public class LoosingStreak {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr [] = {3, 6, 36, 32, 32, 121, 66, 24, 22, 371, 661, 6, 4, 8, -1};
        int temp [] = new int[arr.length];
        processArray(arr);
    }

    static int processArray(int [] arr) {
        int temp [] = new int[arr.length];
        int len = arr.length;
        for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
            if(arr[i+1] <= arr[i]) {
                temp[i] = arr[i];
                System.out.println(temp[i]);
            }

        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

output is: `36, 32, 121, 66, 24, 661, 6, 8` which is incorrect. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a counter, a few index trackers (to track the indices of the chain as well as those of the longest chain) and a max tracker (to track the longest chain) as mentioned in the algorithm given below:

1. As long as the numbers are in decreasing order, increase the value of the counter and also the value of a variable which tracks the index of the element where the order fails.
2. When the order fails, reset the `start` and `end` positions to the index where the order failed and `count` to `0`. Before resetting these values, check if the last chain was the longest (by comparing the value of `max` and `count`) and set the value of `max` accordingly.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 3, 6, 36, 32, 32, 121, 66, 24, 22, 371, 661, 6, 4, 8, -1 };
        int temp[] = new int[arr.length];
        System.out.println(longestLosingStreakLoss(arr));
    }

    static int longestLosingStreakLoss(int[] arr) {
        int start = 0, end = 0, count = 0, max = count, rangeLow = 0, rangeHigh = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i + 1] <= arr[i]) {
                count++;
                end++;
            } else {
                if (count > max) {
                    max = count;
                    rangeHigh = end;
                    rangeLow = rangeHigh - count;
                }
                start = i + 1;
                end = start;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        return rangeLow != rangeHigh ? arr[rangeLow] - arr[rangeHigh] : (count > 0 ? arr[0] - arr[arr.length - 1] : 0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
99
```

Comment: What if the streak ends at the last element of the array, as in {3, 2, 1}? Also, what if you have two streaks of the same length - do you return the one with the max loss?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've corrected the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the current longest streak, and the current max loss for streaks of this length. If you find a streak that's longer than the max, update longest streak and the max loss. If you find a streak that's the same length as the current longest, update the max loss if it's greater.

```
static int processArray(int [] arr) 
{
    int longestStreak = 0;
    int maxLoss = 0;
    for(int j=0, i=1; i<=arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == arr.length || arr[i] > arr[i-1])
        {
            int streak = i - j;
            if(streak > 1 && streak >= longestStreak)
            {
                int loss = arr[j] - arr[i-1];
                if(streak > longestStreak)
                {
                    longestStreak = i-j;                
                    maxLoss = loss;
                }
                else if (loss > maxLoss)
                    maxLoss = loss;                 
            }
            j = i;
        }
    }
    return longestStreak > 0 ? maxLoss : -1;
}
```

Note that I'm taking a streak to be comprised of consecutive numbers that are less than or equal to the previous number, so a singleton wouldn't be a streak.

Test:

```
int test[][] = {{1},
                {1, 1},
                {1, 2, 3},
                {3, 2, 1},
                {3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1},
                {3, 6, 36, 32, 32, 121, 66, 24, 22, 371, 661, 6, 4, 8, -1}};

for(int[] arr : test)
    System.out.format("%s : %d%n", Arrays.toString(arr), processArray(arr));
```

Output:

```
[1] : -1
[1, 1] : 0
[1, 2, 3] : -1
[3, 2, 1] : 2
[3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1] : 3
[3, 6, 36, 32, 32, 121, 66, 24, 22, 371, 661, 6, 4, 8, -1] : 99
```

Comment: Why should it return `-1` for `{1}`? Shouldn't it be `0` because there is no loss in this case?

Comment: I'm taking a streak to be comprised of consecutive numbers that are less than or equal to the previous number, so a singleton wouldn't be a streak. But I agree, it's open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for the longest streak and simultaniously calculate the loss. When you start a streak, calculate its current loss. When an streak ends, you compare the current streak length with the longest streak you haveseen so far. If the new streak is longer, update it and its loss. Than you reset the current streak size and current loss.

```
static int processArray(int [] arr) {
    int streak = 0;
    int maxStreak = 0;
    int loss = 0;
    int maxLoss = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
        if(arr[i+1] <= arr[i]) {
            streak++;
            loss += arr[i] - arr[i+1];     
        }
        else{
            streak = 0;
            loss = 0;
        }
        if(streak > maxStreak){
            maxStreak = streak;
            maxLoss = loss;
        }
    }

    return maxLoss;
}
```

Comment: What if the streak ends at the last element of the array, as in `{3, 2, 1}`?